# Custom Content Regions for a Drupal 7 Home Page

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-templates, drupal-content-types

I am developing a Drupal 7 site with a home page that consists of 5 regions. Each region will need to be editable within the Drupal admin system. Each region at a minimum will need to have an image upload and a text/body field. There may be other additional fields for certain regions. In other words not all of these regions will need the exact same fields.

I am not sure what the best way to set this up in Drupal is. I looked at Blocks but they don't have the ability to customize the fields. And I need my image field to be separate because it will be used as a background image for the region, not displayed inline.

I considered creating a custom content type but I wouldn't want the content editors to be able to create multiple nodes for a given region which would likely cause confusion.

I did see a module Node Limit that seems to limit the number of nodes that can exist for a user or content type but it is still listed as an alpha module.

What have you done to deal with a similar situation?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like creating a custom block would serve you well. It's very easy to do, you can add your own form/fields with `hook_block_configure()` and `hook_block_save()`. [Here's](https://github.com/patrickocoffeyo/BootstrapBlocksModule/blob/master/submodules/BootstrapBlocks_menu/BootstrapBlocks_menu.module) one of my module files that includes custom block with a config form.

You could also possible use the [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/DS) module to add fields into a region, as explained [here](https://drupal.org/node/1795354).

Answer (score 0):

Display Suite is good for configuring a node's fields in a presentation layer.

But your problem could be on the top of that... Maybe your problem is content building, and one of your most powerfull & flexible options is the paragraphs module.

With paragraphs you must create a content type, with the paragraphs bundles inside of it as a field, then create a page and set it to be your front page. Then customize these node types presentation with Display Suite as you need.

I know a content type for a page sounds too much, but depending on your situation this could be your best choice.

Paragraphs module and the Display Suite Module are very powerful together when you need powerful content creation and advanced theming.

If you have any doubt just ask.

Hope that helps.